# Particle hitting particles attached with springs

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, conservation-laws, collision, spring

In classical mechanics if you have a particle moving in two dimensions and it hits a particle at rest although that particle is attached to a spring that is in turn attached to a third particle. Assume all particles have the same mass. How would you solve for the development of the system?

Comment: What approach are you limited by: Newtonian, Lagrangian, or Hamiltonian?

Comment: Any approach would do

Comment: One, two or three dimensions?

Comment: Two dimensions amended question as well

Comment: Then I'd define the kinetic & potential energies with respect to some defined origin and write the Lagrangian. After that, it's a few ODEs. That should sound familiar if you've taken a course in classical mechanics, no?

Comment: Sorry wasn't very clear I've only taken a course in Newtonian mechanics but I think I would understand a answer in Lagrangian mechanics etc I've read a bit about it...

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach: write down conservation of angular momentum, linear momentum, and energy. Assume the impact is elastic and infinitely short duration. In that time the spring didn't move and the third particle didn't come into the equation. That means the problem can be reduced to two simpler problems: two particles that hit elastically (after collision they travel at 90° to each other), and a particle-spring-particle system with an initial condition (one particle has initial momentum).

That should get you going.